# I need help formatting output with PowerShell's Out-File cmdlet

Tags: powershell, file-io

I have a series of documents that are going through the following function designed to count word occurrences in each document. This function works fine outputting to the console, but now I want to generate a text file containting the information, but with the file name appended to each word in the list.

My current console output is:

```
"processing document1 with x unique words occuring as follows"
"word1     12"
"word2      8"
"word3      3"
"word4      4"
"word5      1"
```

I want a delimited file in this format:

```
document1;word1;12
document1;word2;8  
document1;word3;3
document1;word4;4
document1;word1;1
document2;word1;16
document2;word2;11 
document2;word3;9
document2;word4;9
document2;word1;13
```

While the function below gets me the lists of words and occurences, I'm having a hard time figuring out where or how to insert the filename variable so that it prints at the head of each line. MSDN has been less-than helpful, and most of the places I try to insert the variable result in errors (see below)

```
function Count-Words ($docs) {
    $document = get-content $docs 
    $document = [string]::join(" ", $document)        
    $words = $document.split(" `t",[stringsplitoptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)                             
    $uniq = $words | sort -uniq  
    $words | % {$wordhash=@{}} {$wordhash[$_] += 1}
    Write-Host $docs "contains" $wordhash.psbase.keys.count "unique words distributed as follows."
    $frequency = $wordhash.psbase.keys | sort {$wordhash[$_]}
    -1..-25 | %{ $frequency[$_]+" "+$wordhash[$frequency[$_]]} | Out-File c:\out-file-test.txt -append
    $grouped = $words | group | sort count
```

Do I need to create a string to pass to the out-file cmdlet? is this just something I've been putting in the wrong place on the last few tries? I'd like to understand WHY it's going in a particular place as well. Right now I'm just guessing, because I know I have no idea where to put the `out-file` to achieve my selected results.

I've tried formatting my command per powershell help, using `-$docs` and `-FilePath`, but each time I add anything to the `out-file` above that runs successfully, I get the following error:

```
Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "c:\out-file-test.txt" does not bel
ong to the set "unicode,utf7,utf8,utf32,ascii,bigendianunicode,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Sup
ply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.
At C:\c.ps1:39 char:71
+     -1..-25 | %{ $frequency[$_]+" "+$wordhash[$frequency[$_]]} | Out-File <<<<  -$docs -width 1024 c:\users\x46332\co
unt-test.txt -append
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote most of your code. You should utilize objects to make it easier formatting the way you want. This one splits on "space" and groups words together. Try this:

```
Function Count-Words ($paths) {
    $output = @()
    foreach ($path in $paths) {
        $file = Get-ChildItem $path 
        ((Get-Content $file) -join " ").Split(" ", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | Group-Object | Select-Object -Property @{n="FileName";e={$file.BaseName}}, Name, Count | % { 
            $output += "$($_.FileName);$($_.Name);$($_.Count)" 
        }
    }
    $output | Out-File test-out2.txt -Append
}

$filepaths = ".\test.txt", ".\test2.txt"

Count-Words -paths $filepaths
```

It outputs like you asked(document;word;count). If you want documentname to include extension, change `$file.BaseName` to `$file.Name` . Testoutput:

```
test;11;1
test;9;2
test;13;1
test2;word11;5
test2;word1;4
test2;12;1
test2;word2;2
```

Comment: Could you not compile an array of that `PSObject` listing everything, and then use `Export-CSV -delimiter ";" -notypeinfo` to get the output? That would be more efficient from an I/O perspective (and bypassing the pipeline), only writing out to file once.

Comment: @Graimer Thanks! this looks great. This may be an issue with my environment, but when I run the code as noted above, I get this error...`Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Split'.` `At C:\users\x46332\desktop\cgc\counts.ps1:15 char:34` `+         (Get-Content $file).Split <<<< (" ",`  `[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | Group-Object | % {`
    `+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Split:String) [], RuntimeException`
    `+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`   Any ideas? Is there an `include` access a class library?

Comment: ...or perhaps `(Get-Content $file).-split(" ", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | Group-Object`

Comment: @alroc, nope. because he wants append(at least it's in his sample), and append is a PS3.0 feature of export-csv. You could collect every line in an array and output that to minimize IO, but then you'd miss the pipeline effect. I'm not sure which will be faster, but you'd need large files to notice the difference :)

Comment: @dwwilson66 try the updated answer. I'm guessing it didn't get the content properly before running `Split`. I've changed it to save the content to memory first now

Comment: @Graimer `get-content` returns an object[] array, not split method! Maybe you are in powershell v3.0 that do a foreach for you?

Comment: +1 yeah, I noticed it now. Just made the fix =)  PS3.0 automates to conversion to string so you can use split. I also made it save at the end so it will use less IO resources(but more memory) ^^

Comment: @Graimer um.. I think v3.0 do an implict foreach-object for you and not cast! read here: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2012/06/08/implicit-foreach-in-psv3.aspx

Comment: yeah, that's what i meant, just didn't explain properly :)

Comment: @Graimer Argh. Still getting `[System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named split` at or near `$content.Split...`. any other ideas? FWIW, I'm using PS 2.0; that may be my issue.

Comment: try the last updated. I removed `$content.split`, but you must have copied the bugged fix ;) It's now tested on PS2.0 so it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$docs = @("document1", "document2", ...)

$docs | % {
  $doc = $_
  Get-Content $doc `
    | % { $_.split(" `t",[stringsplitoptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) } `
    | Group-Object `
    | select @{n="Document";e={$doc}}, Name, Count
} | Export-CSV output.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInfo
```

If you want to make this into a function you could do it like this:

```
function Count-Words($docs) {
  foreach ($doc in $docs) {
    Get-Content $doc `
      | % { $_.split(" `t",[stringsplitoptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) } `
      | Group-Object `
      | select @{n="Document";e={$doc}}, Name, Count
  }
}

$files = @("document1", "document2", ...)

Count-Words $files | Export-CSV output.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInfo
```

Comment: Works great, except I ONLY get data from the last file in the path. `-append` isn't available to me (I'm running v2.0)' Are you aware of any workarounds for PS2.0 to read a series of files and append the results?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell 2.0 and I get the results for all input files in `output.csv`. However, as a workaround you could try something like `| ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInfo | Out-File output.csv -Append`.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach:

```
function Get-WordCounts ($doc)
{
      $text_ = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($doc.fullname)

      $WordHash = @{}

      $text_ -split '\b' -match '\w+'|
        foreach {$WordHash[$_]++}

      $WordHash.GetEnumerator() | 
       foreach {
         New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                          Word     = $_.Key
                                          Count    = $_.Value
                                         }
               }
  }


$docs = gci c:\testfiles\*.txt |
 sort name

 &{
 foreach ($doc in dir $docs)
        {
           Get-WordCounts $doc |
           sort Count -Descending |
            foreach {
              (&{$doc.Name;$_.Word;$_.Count}) -join ';'  
             }
        }
} | out-file c:\somedir\wordcounts.txt
```

Comment: Nice solution! I'm not seeing an output stpe though, and my efforts to pipe output to `Out_File` hae been unsuccessful. Runs without errors, but thee's nothing to validate. Where would you recommend I place my `Out-File`? I was thinking near the ` -join ';'`...

Comment: An easy way to send foreach-object output to the pipeline is to wrap the loop in &{}.  I updated the answer with an example.